# ASP.NET JSON Web Service Response format

Tags: service, response, json

I have written one simple web service which get product list in JSONText which is string object

Web Service code is below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for JsonWebService
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class JsonWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService 
{

    public JsonWebService () {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string GetProductsJson(string prefix) 
    {
        List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
        if (prefix.Trim().Equals(string.Empty, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            products = ProductFacade.GetAllProducts();
        }
        else
        {
            products = ProductFacade.GetProducts(prefix);
        }
        //yourobject is your actula object (may be collection) you want to serialize to json
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(products.GetType());
        //create a memory stream
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        //serialize the object to memory stream
        serializer.WriteObject(ms, products);
        //convert the serizlized object to string
        string jsonString = Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        //close the memory stream
        ms.Close();
        return jsonString;
    }
}
```

**now it give me resoponse like below :**

{"d":"[{\"ProductID\":1,\"ProductName\":\"Product 1\"},{\"ProductID\":2,\"ProductName\":\"Product 2\"},{\"ProductID\":3,\"ProductName\":\"Product 3\"},{\"ProductID\":4,\"ProductName\":\"Product 4\"},{\"ProductID\":5,\"ProductName\":\"Product 5\"},{\"ProductID\":6,\"ProductName\":\"Product 6\"},{\"ProductID\":7,\"ProductName\":\"Product 7\"},{\"ProductID\":8,\"ProductName\":\"Product 8\"},{\"ProductID\":9,\"ProductName\":\"Product 9\"},{\"ProductID\":10,\"ProductName\":\"Product 10\"}]"}

**But i am looking for below out put**

[{"ProductID":1,"ProductName":"Product 1"},{"ProductID":2,"ProductName":"Product 2"},{"ProductID":3,"ProductName":"Product 3"},{"ProductID":4,"ProductName":"Product 4"},{"ProductID":5,"ProductName":"Product 5"},{"ProductID":6,"ProductName":"Product 6"},{"ProductID":7,"ProductName":"Product 7"},{"ProductID":8,"ProductName":"Product 8"},{"ProductID":9,"ProductName":"Product 9"},{"ProductID":10,"ProductName":"Product 10"}]

can any one tell me what is actual problem

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

First there was a change with ASP.NET 3.5 for security reasons Microsoft added the "d" to the response.  Below is a link from Dave Ward at the Encosia that talks about what your seeing:
[A breaking change between versions of ASP.NET AJAX](http://encosia.com/2009/02/10/a-breaking-change-between-versions-of-aspnet-ajax/).  He has several posts that talks about this that can help you further with processing JSON and ASP.NET

Comment: Thanks ewrankin for you kind reply 

but my problem is i have to go with asp.net 2.0 framework so will you please suggest me how can i achieve this.

please if you have any other option than please tell me

Comment: I'm sorry I guess I don't understand your comment.  Do you want to go to ASP.NET 2.0?  Because based on the JSON response you are receiving you are using ASP.NET 3.5 because of the additional "d" that is being added.  Or are you asking how to work with the "d" in the response you are receiving.

Comment: I have work with your suggestion but still it give me same out put with unwanted '\' and not give me output like 

{"d":"[{"ProductID":1,"ProductName":"Product 1"},{"ProductID":2,"ProductName":"Product 2"},{"ProductID":3,"ProductName":"Product 3"},{"ProductID":4,"ProductName":"Product 4"},{"ProductID":5,"ProductName":"Product 5"},{"ProductID":6,"ProductName":"Product 6"},{"ProductID":7,"ProductName":"Product 7"},{"ProductID":8,"ProductName":"Product 8"},{"ProductID":9,"ProductName":"Product 9"},{"ProductID":10,"ProductName":"Product 10"}]"}

Comment: That's because you are returning a single string so it's escaping the quotes in the response.  Try changing your return type to List<Product> and returning "products".  You don't need to serialize the string yourself, ASP.NET with the WebMethod attribute will take care of that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you just remove the

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
```

from the method, and you return the **jsonString** that you serialized using the JavaScriptSerializer you will get exactelly the output that you were looking for.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but if I remove this ResponseFormat, then the output is wrapped with a new tag:

<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">

Answer (score 0):

Notice that u have double quotes beside ur array in your response.In this way u return json format not json object from ur web method.Json format is a string.Therefore u have to use json.parse() function in order to parse json string to json object.If u dont want to use parse fuction,u have to remove serialize in ur web method.Thus u get a json object.

Comment: u dont have to add response method on ur web method.If u send ur paremeters in jsonformat like this "{'prefix':'asd'}",.net will return response in jsonobject.Otherwise if u send ur data in form-encoded or json object like this {'prefix':'asd'} without double quotes.the data will come wrapped in xml.So u have to use response format in this time

Answer (score -1):

in .net web service

```
[WebMethod]
public string Android_DDD(string KullaniciKey, string Durum, string PersonelKey)
{
    return EU.EncodeToBase64("{\"Status\":\"OK\",\"R\":[{\"ImzaTipi\":\"Paraf\", \"Personel\":\"Ali Veli üğişçöıÜĞİŞÇÖI\", \"ImzaDurumTipi\":\"Tamam\", \"TamamTar\":\"1.1.2003 11:21\"},{\"ImzaTipi\":\"İmza\", \"Personel\":\"Ali Ak\", \"ImzaDurumTipi\":\"Tamam\", \"TamamTar\":\"2.2.2003 11:21\"}]}");
}

static public string EncodeToBase64(string toEncode)
{
    UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
    byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(toEncode);
    string returnValue = System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    return returnValue;
}
```

in android

```
private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is)
{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    try
    {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            is.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

private void LoadJsonDataFromASPNET()
{
    try
    {              
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost(this.WSURL + "/WS.asmx/Android_DDD");
        JSONObject jsonObjSend = new JSONObject();
        jsonObjSend.put("KullaniciKey", "value_1");
        jsonObjSend.put("Durum", "value_2");
        jsonObjSend.put("PersonelKey", "value_3");
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonObjSend.toString());
        httpPostRequest.setEntity(se);
        httpPostRequest.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPostRequest.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        // httpPostRequest.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip"); // only set this parameter if you would like to use gzip compression

        HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpPostRequest);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null)
        {
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            String resultString = convertStreamToString(instream);
            instream.close();
            resultString = resultString.substring(6, resultString.length()-3);
            resultString = new String(android.util.Base64.decode(resultString, 0), "UTF-8");
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(resultString);
            String oDurum = object.getString("Status");
            if (oDurum.equals("OK"))
            {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(object.getString("R"));
                if (jsonArray.length() > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String ImzaTipi = jsonObject.getString("ImzaTipi");
                        String Personel = jsonObject.getString("Personel");
                        String ImzaDurumTipi = jsonObject.getString("ImzaDurumTipi");
                        String TamamTar = jsonObject.getString("TamamTar");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ImzaTipi:" + ImzaTipi + " Personel:" + Personel + " ImzaDurumTipi:" + ImzaDurumTipi + " TamamTar:" + TamamTar, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }   
                }
            }   
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: when json object pass .net to androi app (with [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] ) the response from android has <xml... tag not püre json data