# How to parse JSON without JSON.NET library?

Tags: c#, json, windows-8

I'm trying to build a Metro application for Windows 8 on Visual Studio 2011.
and while I'm trying to do that, I'm having some issues on how to parse `JSON` without `JSON.NET` library (It doesn't support the metro applications yet).

Anyway, I want to parse this:

```
{
   "name":"Prince Charming",
   "artist":"Metallica",
   "genre":"Rock and Metal",
   "album":"Reload",
   "album_image":"http:\/\/up203.siz.co.il\/up2\/u2zzzw4mjayz.png",
   "link":"http:\/\/f2h.co.il\/7779182246886"
}
```

Comment: You can do it with string manipulation like those of us did before `JSON.NET` and other libraries came about.

Comment: Use JavascriptSerializer. Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405458/return-json-data-from-asmx-web-service

Comment: You shouldn't be asking this, MS has not shown more love for anything like it has to Json. There's `Json` in `System.Web.Helpers`, there's `JsonQueryStringConverter` in `System.ServiceModel.Web`, there's `JavascriptSerializer` in `System.Web.Script.Serialization`, `DataContractJsonSerializer` in `System.Runtime.Serialization.Json`... Not at all confusing.

Comment: Heck MS has even decided to include third party `Json.NET` in its ASP.NET Web API. If you thought that wasn't enough, MS is coming up with `System.Json` but currently is unfit for consumption. And Windows 8 is a special case for MS, so there is also `JsonValue` in `Windows.Data.Json` which is only for Windows 8 and above.

Comment: As of late 2016: It seems that [Microsoft has embraced Json.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) and possibly abandoned the never-officially-released `System.Json`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.json%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 talks about "preview" and the [Nuget package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Json) is both (still) labeled "Beta" and has been _unlisted_, suggesting deprecation. (There is a released `System.Json`, but it is Silverlight-only).

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You can use the classes found in the [System.Json Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.json%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which were added in .NET 4.5. You need to add a reference to the [System.Runtime.Serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization(v=vs.110).aspx) assembly

The [JsonValue.Parse() Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.json.jsonvalue.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) parses JSON text and returns a [JsonValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.json.jsonvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
JsonValue value = JsonValue.Parse(@"{ ""name"":""Prince Charming"", ...");
```

If you pass a string with a JSON object, you should be able to cast the value to a [JsonObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.json.jsonobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
using System.Json;


JsonObject result = value as JsonObject;

Console.WriteLine("Name .... {0}", (string)result["name"]);
Console.WriteLine("Artist .. {0}", (string)result["artist"]);
Console.WriteLine("Genre ... {0}", (string)result["genre"]);
Console.WriteLine("Album ... {0}", (string)result["album"]);
```

The classes are quite similar to those found in the [System.Xml.Linq Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.aspx).

Comment: I dont have System.Json namespace... I'm using visual studio 2011 ultimate and when im trying to add reference it gives me an empty list...

Comment: You need to add a reference to the System.Runtime.Serialization assembly.

Comment: It seems to be in the Windows.Data.Json; now as I can see in my Metro App.

Comment: Use Nuget to install system.json :   
Install-Package System.Json

Comment: Is there an example of this strongly-typed with generics? Would like to not waste the time writing something that I don't have to. :)

Comment: If the package cannot be found, make sure you add the version number. Example: `PM> Install-Package System.Json -Version 4.0.20126.16343`. Find the current version here: http://nuget.org/packages/System.Json

Comment: System.Json is still in beta and so Nuget package seems to be the way to get it. It is not built-in the most recent full Framework V 4.5.1. Personally I like Json.Net's API which is much less verbose and faster than Windows.Data.Json or System.Json. See http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/JsonNetVsWindowsDataJson.htm

Comment: cant find system.json

Comment: @krowe2 - Last time I checked Json.NET was MIT licenced: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/LICENSE.md

Comment: The type or namespace name 'JsonValue' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) I'm targeting .NET Framework 4.7.2 and I have added a reference to the System.Runtime.Serialization assembly. I want to avoid using any NuGet packages, otherwise I might as well just use NewtonSoft.

Answer (score 41):

I use this...but have never done any metro app development, so I don't know of any restrictions on libraries available to you. (note, you'll need to mark your classes as with DataContract and DataMember attributes)

```
public static class JSONSerializer<TType> where TType : class
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Serializes an object to JSON
    /// </summary>
    public static string Serialize(TType instance)
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(TType));
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(stream, instance);
            return Encoding.Default.GetString(stream.ToArray());
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// DeSerializes an object from JSON
    /// </summary>
    public static TType DeSerialize(string json)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(json)))
        {
            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(TType));
            return serializer.ReadObject(stream) as TType;
        }
    }
}
```

So, if you had a class like this...

```
[DataContract]
public class MusicInfo
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Artist { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Genre { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Album { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string AlbumImage { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Link { get; set; }

}
```

Then you would use it like this...

```
var musicInfo = new MusicInfo
{
     Name = "Prince Charming",
     Artist = "Metallica",
     Genre = "Rock and Metal",
     Album = "Reload",
     AlbumImage = "http://up203.siz.co.il/up2/u2zzzw4mjayz.png",
     Link = "http://f2h.co.il/7779182246886"
};

// This will produce a JSON String
var serialized = JSONSerializer<MusicInfo>.Serialize(musicInfo);

// This will produce a copy of the instance you created earlier
var deserialized = JSONSerializer<MusicInfo>.DeSerialize(serialized);
```

Comment: how do I use it? it keeps asking me for TType, whats that?

Comment: If your type (class) was called MyType, you would use it like this: JSONSerializer<MyType>.Serialize() and JSONSerializer<MyType>.Deserialize(myInstanceOfMyType)

Comment: Looks like dtb has a newer native way (answered above) if you're using v4.5 of the Framework.

Comment: You have to use Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray()); if you want to support unicode.

Comment: How do you deal, if you have an object inside your custom object that does not have a DataContract and DataMember attribute?

Comment: @ctorx How to deal same problem for list of objects i.e. if we want to write 100s of objects to a file and then restore same file's contents into a list of same objects?

Answer (score 11):

For those who do not have 4.5, Here is my library function that reads json. It requires a project reference to `System.Web.Extensions`.

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

public object DeserializeJson<T>(string Json)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer JavaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<T>(Json);
}
```

Usually, json is written out based on a contract. That contract can and usually will be codified in a class (`T`). Sometimes you can take a word from the json and search the object browser to find that type.

Example usage:

Given the json

```json
{"logEntries":[],"value":"My Code","text":"My Text","enabled":true,"checkedIndices":[],"checkedItemsTextOverflows":false}
```

You could parse it into a `RadComboBoxClientState` object like this:

```cs
string ClientStateJson = Page.Request.Form("ReportGrid1_cboReportType_ClientState");
RadComboBoxClientState RadComboBoxClientState = DeserializeJson<RadComboBoxClientState>(ClientStateJson);
return RadComboBoxClientState.Value;
```

[Link to docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer?view=netframework-4.8.1)

Answer (score 7):

I needed a JSON serializer and deserializer without any 3rd party dependency or nuget, that can support old systems, so you don't have to choose between Newtonsoft.Json, System.Text.Json, DataContractSerializer, JavaScriptSerializer, etc. depending on the target platform.

So I have started this "**ZeroDepJson**" open source (MIT licensed) project here:

https://github.com/smourier/ZeroDepJson

It's just **one C# file** `ZeroDepJson.cs`, compatible with .NET Framework 4.x to .NET Core/5/6/7+.

Note absolute performance is not a goal. Although its performance is, I hope, decent, if you're after the best performing JSON serializer / deserializer ever, then don't use this.

Comment: I love libraries like this. Probably will use this one for a SQL SSIS package script that needs to parse JSON from a REST response. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried using `JavaScriptSerializer` ?
There's also `DataContractJsonSerializer`

Comment: Nope, can you explain to me whats that? thanx dude

Comment: DataContract: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb908432.aspx
JavaScriptSerializer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx

Comment: Re `JavaScriptSerializer`: As of this writing, its [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) recommends using [Json.NET](http://json.net) instead.

Answer (score 3):

I have written a small construct to do that long back, it requires **`System.Runtime.Serialization.Json`** namespace. It uses `DataContractJsonSerializer` to serialize & deserialize `object` with a static method `JConvert`.

It works with small set of data but haven't tested with big data source.

#### JsonHelper.cs

```cs
// Json Serializer without NewtonSoft
public static class JsonHelper
{
    public static R JConvert<P,R>(this P t)
    {       
        if(typeof(P) == typeof(string))
        {
            var return1 =  (R)(JsonDeserializer<R>(t as string));
            return return1;
        }
        else
        {
            var return2 =  (JsonSerializer<P>(t));
            R result = (R)Convert.ChangeType(return2, typeof(R));
            return result;
        }   
    }
    
    private static String JsonSerializer<T>(T t)
    {
        var stream1 = new MemoryStream();
        var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        ser.WriteObject(stream1, t);
        stream1.Position = 0;
        var sr = new StreamReader(stream1);     
        return (sr.ReadToEnd());
    }
    
    private static T JsonDeserializer<T>(string jsonString)
    {
        T deserializedUser = default(T);
        var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString));
        var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        deserializedUser = (T)ser.ReadObject(ms);// as T;
        ms.Close();
        return deserializedUser;
    }
}
```

#### Syntax:

To use the `JsonHelper` you need to call

```
JConvert<string,object>(str); //to Parse string to non anonymous <object>
JConvert<object,string>(obj); //to convert <obj> to string
```

### Example:

Suppose we have a class `person`

```cs
public class person
{
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
}

var obj = new person();//"vinod","srivastav");
obj.FirstName = "vinod";
obj.LastName = "srivastav";
```

To convert the `person` object we can call:

```cs
var asText = JsonHelper.JConvert<person,string>(obj); //to convert <obj> to string

var asObject = JsonHelper.JConvert<string,person>(asText); //to convert string to non-anonymous object
```

---

## EDIT:2023

Since the construct & was a bit difficult to use & understand, here is another simple implementation to imitate `Javascript JSON` object with`JSON.stringify()` & `JSON.parse()`. It also have an extension function `ToJson()` to work with anonymous objects which uses `System.Web.Script.Serialization` from `system.Web.Extensions.dll` to serialize object tot json.

```cs
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;

public static class JSON
{

    public static string ToJson(this object dataObject)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return js.Serialize(dataObject);        
    }
    
    public static T ToObject<T>(this string serializedData)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var deserializedResult = js.Deserialize<T>(serializedData);
        return deserializedResult;
    }
    
    public static String Stringify<T>(T t)
    {
        var inmemory = new MemoryStream();
        var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        ser.WriteObject(inmemory, t);
        return (Encoding.UTF8.GetString(inmemory.ToArray()));
    }
    
    public static T Parse<T>(string jsonString)
    {
        T deserializedUser = default(T);
        var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString));
        var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        deserializedUser = (T)ser.ReadObject(ms);// as T;
        ms.Close();
        return deserializedUser;
    }
}
```

Now to use this one you simply have to write:

```cs
//to convert <obj> to string
var asText = JSON.Stringify(obj); 

//to convert string to non-anonymous object
var asObject = JSON.Parse<person>(asText); 

//for anonymous object
var ao = new {Name="Vinod", Surname = "Srivastav" };
var asText = ao.ToJson();
```

---

## In .NET 6.0

With `.NET 6.0` you just need to add

```
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
```

**Json.cs**

```cs
public static class JSON
{
    public static string Stringify<T>(T t)
    {
        string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(t);
        return jsonString;
    }

    public static T Parse<T>(string jsonString)
    {
        T deserializedObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonString)!;
        return deserializedObject;
    }
}
```

And it still runs the above example:
[image]

Comment: how to use ? example ?

Comment: @GrayProgrammerz I have updated the answer with an example, see if it works for you

Comment: Thanks. between can I use it dynamically ? without `person` ? like [Utf8Json](https://github.com/neuecc/Utf8Json#dynamic-deserialization) ?

Comment: @GrayProgrammerz I have again updated the answer to include `ToJson()` this extension will work with anonymous object see example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DataContractJsonSerializer`. See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx) for more details.

Comment: I tried that with this code { DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Song));
                Song item = (Song)ser.ReadObject(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(song)));
                Debug.WriteLine(item.name); } and it gives me an error

Comment: The error is Type 'Test1.Song' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.

Comment: @EliRevah - You need to define the data contract for the deserialization with the [DataContract] attribute for the class and add [DataMember] attribute for each member.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Text;

namespace OTL
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Before usage: Define your class, sample:
    /// [DataContract]
    ///public class MusicInfo
    ///{
    ///   [DataMember(Name="music_name")]
    ///   public string Name { get; set; }
    ///   [DataMember]
    ///   public string Artist{get; set;}
    ///}
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    public class OTLJSON<T> where T : class
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Serializes an object to JSON
        /// Usage: string serialized = OTLJSON&lt;MusicInfo&gt;.Serialize(musicInfo);
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="instance"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string Serialize(T instance)
        {
            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                serializer.WriteObject(stream, instance);
                return Encoding.Default.GetString(stream.ToArray());
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// DeSerializes an object from JSON
        /// Usage:  MusicInfo deserialized = OTLJSON&lt;MusicInfo&gt;.Deserialize(json);
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="json"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static T Deserialize(string json)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
                throw new Exception("Json can't empty");
            else
                try
                {
                    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(json)))
                    {

                        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
                        return serializer.ReadObject(stream) as T;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Json can't convert to Object because it isn't correct format.");
                }
        }
    }
}
```