# Where is System.Json.DLL?

Tags: asp.net, .net, json

I'm trying to follow some examples using JSON with the Http Client, but they refer to a System.Json.DLL that I cannot find.  See [this reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.json.jsonobject%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to see the reference to System.Json.DLL, but I cannot find that DLL installed on my machine.  Is it an add-on?  I googled but found no other result...

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Json does not exist in the namespace System](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859319/json-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-system)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's a class library for Silverlight, but not [ASP] .NET.

If you really wanted to use it, there is an equivalent version in .net 4.5,

I would suggest you to take a look at [Json.Net](http://nuget.org/packages/System.Json), it's one of the most popular .NET JSON libraries.

Comment: Huh, I must have gotten the sample mixed up then.  Thanks.

Comment: Not a problem. If you think this has helped you to resolve your issue, please mark it as answer. :)

Comment: Am I missing something?  That namespace does not exist in that dll for me at:  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll`

Comment: @DavidSherret as of now it is deprecated.