# using System.Json does not exist in .net 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-4, dll

I have copied following code :

```
protected override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
        {
            // don't serialize JsonValue structure use default for that
            if (type == typeof(JsonValue) || type == typeof(JsonObject) || type == typeof(JsonArray))
                return false;

            return true;
        }

protected override bool CanReadType(Type type)
        {
            if (type == typeof(IKeyValueModel))
                return false;

            return true;
        }
```

in this, JsonValue,JsonObject,JsonArray,IKeyValueModel wants System.Json dll which is not available in .net 4.5 framework.

I have updated nuget package to 5.0, but still that still that dll is not available. Anyone can provide me direct dll or can give me steps for System.Json dll?

**I have tried with Silverlight's System.Json.dll, but it's not working at all**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is System.Json.DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812466/where-is-system-json-dll)