# System.Json depreacted. What is the alternative?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, system.json

I'm trying to implement a JSON api for my mobile application. Altough many of samples use System.Json, it is deperecated now. What is its current replacment in .NET?

Comment: `Json` is a method defined in the base controller to return a json representation of the object you are passing to it. Behind the scene it uses the Newtonsoft Json serializer to do that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859319/215552

Comment: One can easily do a web search for ".NET JSON" and find many useful results. Why did you ask here?

Comment: @mason I did reword the question. But deprecation of an API/Library is normal and It would be normal to ask for its current replacement. like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27141279/setbackgrounddrawable-deprecated) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27141279/setbackgrounddrawable-deprecated).

Comment: @VSB The existence of questions that break our rules doesn't excuse creating more questions that break our rules. It's off topic.

Comment: @mason I do not think this question, nor the other two cited, actually break the rules. This is a purely technical question about the namespace of the library included in .NET that replaced an old one. I am all for rules, but applying them too strictly when they solve nothing doesn't help. This question will NOT attract opiniated answers nor spam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most used library is Json.net

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: Even Microsoft relies on it for ASP.Net MVC 4 WebAPI and 5... Also, with a ASP.NET MVC WebAPI, you really should not have much to do with JSON manually, your controller just needs to return a serializable object (or a collection of them).

Comment: Let's not answer [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) questions. It only encourages more.

Comment: Why is it off topic? It's a perfectly valid question if you ask me.

Comment: @DrunkenCodeMonkey From the page I linked to above: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: I think mason is actually off here. This is not a recommendation, it is a library that has been deprecated and then replaced by Microsoft. No opinions necessary here.