# Serializing Dictionary< String, Dictionary< String, String > > in any form (Json, xml etc.)

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8

Serializing Dictionary< String, Dictionary< String, String > > to the point where it can be stored, and later de serialized.
I've done quite a bit of googling and can't find a class, or function that is compatible with .NET 4.5 Completely.

Comment: i.e. Use IXmlSerializable and create your custom logic.

Comment: See this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495647/serialize-class-containing-dictionary-member

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i found the solution is to use [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx)

```
public String Serialize(Dictionary<int, Dictionary<String, String>> all)
        {

            String abc = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(all, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings
                        {
                            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
                            TypeNameAssemblyFormat = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple
                        });
            return abc;
        }

         public Dictionary<int, Dictionary<String, String>> DeSerialize(String text)
         {

             Dictionary<int, Dictionary<String, String>> abc;
             abc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int, Dictionary<String, String>>>(text, new JsonSerializerSettings
             {
                 TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
                 TypeNameAssemblyFormat = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple,
             });
             return abc;
         }
```

Answer (score 2):

The out-of-the-box [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) should be able to cope with your dictionary. It should give quite compact output, too.

```
var source = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>
{
    { "one", new Dictionary<string, string> { { "a", "1a"}, { "b", "1b" } } },
    { "two", new Dictionary<string, string> { { "a", "2a"}, { "b", "2b" } } }
};

var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

// This gives {"one":{"a":"1a","b":"1b"},"two":{"a":"2a","b":"2b"}}
string serialized = serializer.Serialize(source);

// This gives a clone of the original dictionary.
var deserialized = serializer.Deserialize
    <Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>(serialized);
```

Comment: But JavascriptSerializer doesn't exist in Metro for some reason :\

Comment: You can't add a reference to `System.Web.Extensions`? In that case, according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573119/how-to-parse-json-without-json-net-library), you could try the [`System.Json`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.json.aspx) namespace, but I'm afraid I'm unfamiliar with it and don't have access to 4.5 so I can't offer any further help.

Comment: Thats fine, Thanks for all your help. And nope can't add reference to System.Web.Extensions :\

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [SerializableDictionary](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/141955/Both-XML-and-Binary-Serializable-Dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

you should use following, it'll make your life easer.

[StorageHelper](http://codepaste.net/gtu5mq)

or use

[WinRT XAML Toolkit](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/)