# C# Sort JSON string keys

Tags: c#, .net, json, string, sorting

I'd like to convert the JSON string

```
"{ \"birthday\": \"1988-03-18\", \"address\": { \"state\": 24, \"city\": 8341, \"country\": 1 } }"
```

to

```
"{ \"address\": { \"city\": 8341, \"country\": 1, \"state\": 24 }, \"birthday\": \"1988-03-18\" }"
```

NOTE: I'm not using the sorted version for communication (because the key order doesn't really matter), I need a sorted version to perform local tests (by comparing JSON strings).

---

**EDIT:** I4V pointed a solution that uses [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/), I would rather use a solution that doesn't need to include any 3rd party library (actually I'm using the built in System.Json in my application)

---

I posted a gist with the solution provided by I4V + some testing [here](https://gist.github.com/4575133). Thank you all.

Comment: Hmm... Tempting though it sounds, I'd venture that the better solution would be a slightly deeper inspection of the JSON rather than a string comparision. Given that the enumeration of properties in JS not determined by the spec, the order of object properties should not be relied upon because it's really meaningless to order the properties of a json serialization. ECMA-262, section 12.6.4: The mechanics of enumerating the properties ... is implementation dependent.

Comment: @spender I agree with you that the JSON key order are meaningless and string comparison shouldn't be used for comparing large/complex JSON objects. But a JSON string sorter may be useful for very specific situations (as mine)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I will use [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) for this

```
string json = @"{ ""birthday"": ""1988-03-18"", ""address"": { ""state"": 24, ""city"": 8341, ""country"": 1 } }";
var jObj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
Sort(jObj);
string newJson = jObj.ToString();
```

---

```
void Sort(JObject jObj)
{
    var props = jObj.Properties().ToList();
    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        prop.Remove();
    }

    foreach (var prop in props.OrderBy(p=>p.Name))
    {
        jObj.Add(prop);
        if(prop.Value is JObject)
            Sort((JObject)prop.Value);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

A try with `System.Json` but I am not sure about `OrderByDescending` ( or `OrderBy`).

```
var jObj = (System.Json.JsonObject)System.Json.JsonObject.Parse(json);
Sort2(jObj);
var newJson = jObj.ToString();
```

---

```
void Sort2(System.Json.JsonObject jObj)
{
    var props = jObj.ToList();
    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        jObj.Remove(prop.Key);
    }

    foreach (var prop in props.OrderByDescending(p => p.Key))
    {
        jObj.Add(prop);
        if (prop.Value is System.Json.JsonObject)
            Sort2((System.Json.JsonObject)prop.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. But I'm using the built in System.Json in my app, so I'd rather use a solution that doesn't need a 3rd party lib.

Comment: Did you mean to remove the properties from the JObj and not the property list? Looks like you are removing all the items from the property list then trying to sort and enumerate it.

Comment: @EduardoCoelho You can still use this solution with System.Json, just instead of deserializing with JSON.NET deserialize with System.Json, check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573119/how-to-parse-json-without-json-net-library

Comment: Thanks @I4V, I created a gist with your implementation + basic tests  https://gist.github.com/4575133

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you for this. It helped me through a problem.

Comment: It looks like your solution for Json.Net doesn't work for properties of type JArray. Then `if(prop.Value is JObject)` is not triggering recursive call.

Comment: @OlegDeribas This is a working code. If you think you found a bug, post the json, the code you are using.

Comment: @I4V Here is example of JSON with array:
`{
 "data": [{
  "z": 1,
  "a": 2
 }, {
  "z": 3,
  "a": 4
 }]
}`

Comment: @OlegDeribas It is an **JObject** containing a property *data* which is an array.

Comment: @I4V Yes. Property _data_ is an array of **JObject**s. And these **JObject**s' properties don't get sorted because recursive call doesn't go inside **JArray**.

Comment: Does this approach still work? Stringifying a JObject with ToString just changes the order again it seems, even if the properties are added in the correct order.

Answer (score 6):

I know this may be a little late but, in case of you need to sort the internal arrays of data too (I just needed it):

```
static void Sort(JObject jObj)
{
    var props = jObj.Properties().ToList();
    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        prop.Remove();
    }

    foreach (var prop in props.OrderBy(p => p.Name))
    {
        jObj.Add(prop);
        if (prop.Value is JObject)
            Sort((JObject)prop.Value);
        if (prop.Value is JArray)
        {
            Int32 iCount = prop.Value.Count();
            for (Int32 iIterator = 0; iIterator < iCount; iIterator++)
                if (prop.Value[iIterator] is JObject)
                    Sort((JObject)prop.Value[iIterator]);
        }
    }
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

By using [this approach you can retrieve a dynamic object with your json data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7485047/340760)

At the `DynamicJsonConverter` create a `SortedDictionary` instead

```
var d = new SortedDictionary<string, object>(dictionary);
// TODO: code to sort inner objects
return new DynamicJsonObject(d);
```

Then you can use

```
string jsonStr = "{\"B\":\"2\",\"A\":\"1\"}";
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
jss.RegisterConverters(new JavaScriptConverter[] { new DynamicJsonConverter() });

dynamic json = jss.Deserialize(jsonStr, typeof(object)) as dynamic;

string result = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize((json as DynamicJsonObject).Dictionary);
```

And `result` will have the expected output.

Comment: Thanks @BrunoLM, however I ended up using the plain `System.Json.JsonObject`.