# JavaScriptSerializer serialize result with sorted JSON keys

Tags: c#, serialization

I am using

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string s = serializer.Serialize(myresultOld);
```

to serialize an object `myresultOld`

Can I output the serialize results sorted by JSON keys?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417235/c-sharp-sort-json-string-keys

Comment: Sort it before that in the myResultObject ... Also you can use jquery.sort

Comment: May I ask why you need your JSON sorted by key?