# C# sort JSON for value

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON file from our CRM:

```
[{"name": "erwin", "type":"ma", "id":"129"}, {"name": "hans", "type":"tf", "id":"12"}]
```

Now I need to sort this JSON by ID value, in my example the output should be:

```
[{"name": "hans", "type":"tf", "id":"12"}, {"name": "erwin", "type":"ma", "id":"129"}]
```

I already found this thread: [C# Sort JSON string keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417235/c-sharp-sort-json-string-keys)

But I don`t know how to load my JSON file into the method from the solution.
Maybe with json.net?
Regards,

Francis

EDIT:

```
string sourcePath = @Settings.Default.folder;
            string pathToSourceFile = Path.Combine(sourcePath, "myfile.json");
            var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Gesamtplan>>(File.ReadAllText(pathToSourceFile));
```

Comment: When you say `load my JSON file into the method from the solution`, you mean [embedded resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2c9s1d7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)?

Comment: No, sorry. I mean that I don`t know how to load my file into the code from the solution...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class RootObject
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}

private string AscMyJson(string json)
{
    var listOb = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);
    var descListOb = listOb.OrderBy(x => x.id);
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(descListOb);
}
```

Comment: OP wants it ascending use `OrderBy` instead of `OrderByDescending`

Comment: Looks great, but now the order is wrong. How can we switch the order? At the moment, the ID which should be the last is on top of the file :)

Comment: Got it - var listOb = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);
        var descListOb = listOb.OrderBy(x => x.id);
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(descListOb);