# Sorting JObject inside array by a field value

Tags: c#, json, sorting, json.net

I have a JSON string like below:

```
{
  "MetaData": {
    "ResourcesUsed": 1
  },
  "Result": [
    {
      "locations": [
        {
          "country": "Papua New Guinea",
          "city": "Jacquinot Bay",
          "locTypeAttributes": {
            "localDate": "2018-10-08T04:21:00-07:00",
            "utcDate": "2018-10-08T04:21:00-07:00",
          },
          "point": {
            "coordinates": [
              151.52,
              -5.6
            ],
            "type": "Point"
          }
        },{
          "country": "Papua New Guinea2",
          "city": "Jacquinot Bay2",
          "locTypeAttributes": {
            "localDate": "2018-10-08T04:21:00-07:00",
            "utcDate": "2018-10-02T04:21:00-07:00",
          },
          "point": {
            "coordinates": [
              151.52,
              -5.6
            ],
            "type": "Point"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I converted it to a JSON object using Newtonsoft.  What I want to do is to sort the `locations` array(s) inside the `Result` array by the `utcDate` field nested in each `locations` item.  I found the following thread: [C# Sort JSON string keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417235/c-sharp-sort-json-string-keys?lq=1). However, I could not still implement it since I have arrays inside my object, while that question deals purely with sorting objects inside objects alphabetically by property name.

Here is a piece of code that I wrote so far:

```
public string GenerateJson()
{
     var model = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data);
     Sort(model);
}
private void Sort(JObject jObj)
{
    var props = jObj["Result"][0]["locations"].ToList();
    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        prop.Remove();
    }

    foreach (var prop in props.OrderBy(p => p.Name))
    {
        jObj.Add(prop);
        if (prop.Value is JObject)
            Sort((JObject)prop.Value);
        if (prop.Value is JArray)
        {
            Int32 iCount = prop.Value.Count();
            for (Int32 iIterator = 0; iIterator < iCount; iIterator++)
                if (prop.Value[iIterator] is JObject)
                    Sort((JObject)prop.Value[iIterator]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not deserialize to a custom class and then sort it  (normally)

Comment: @Disaffected1070452 that's my last resort, I was trying to avoid creating any custom class.

Comment: Do you want to sort the `"Result": []` array, or do you want to sort each `"Result[*].locations"` array?  Because the locations themselves are an array so there might in principle be more than one, each with its own `utcDate`.  And if you do want to sort the `"Results"` array how do you want to deal with the situation where a result has multiple locations with multiple `utcDate` values?  [C# Sort JSON string keys](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14417235/3744182) is for recursively sorting a tree of objects by property name so it doesn't really apply here.

Comment: @dbc I just simplified the JSON string, so in Result, we will always have one array of locations, I want to sort that array by `utcDate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort each individual `"Result[*].locations"` array using LINQ as follows:

```
// Load the JSON without parsing or converting any dates.
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(data, new JsonSerializerSettings{ DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None });

// Construct a serializer that converts all DateTime values to UTC
var serializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(new JsonSerializerSettings{ DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc });

foreach (var locations in model.SelectTokens("Result[*].locations").OfType<JArray>())
{
    // Then sort the locations by utcDate converting the value to UTC at this time.
    var query = from location in locations
                let utcDate = location.SelectToken("locTypeAttributes.utcDate").ToObject<DateTime>(serializer)
                orderby utcDate
                select location;
    locations.ReplaceAll(query.ToList());
}
```

Notes:

- The JSON is initially loaded using [`DateParseHandling.None`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DateParseHandling.htm) to prevent the `"localDate"` and `"utcDate"` strings from being prematurely interpreted as `DateTime` objects with a uniform [`DateTime.Kind`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.kind?view=netframework-4.7.2).

  (For a discussion of how Json.NET interprets strings that look like dates, see *[Serializing Dates in JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm)*.)
- We then iterate through all `"locations"` arrays using [`SelectTokens("Result[*].locations")`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectTokens.htm) where `[*]` is the [JSONPath](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) wildcard character, selecting all entries in the `"Results"` array.
- We then order each `"locations"` array by deserializing the nested `locTypeAttributes.utcDate` to a UTC date, then ordering using LINQ.
- Finally the array is updated using [`JArray.ReplaceAll()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_ReplaceAll.htm).
- If any `locTypeAttributes.utcDate` property is missing, an exception will be thrown.  You could instead deserialize to `DateTime?` if that is a possibility.

Working sample .Net fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bR0NfE).