# POSTing JSON to URL via WebClient in C#

Tags: c#, webclient

I have some JavaScript code that I need to convert to C#. My JavaScript code POSTs some JSON to a web service that's been created. This JavaScript code works fine and looks like the following:

```
var vm = { k: "1", a: "2", c: "3", v: "4" };
$.ajax({
  url: "http://www.mysite.com/1.0/service/action",
  type: "POST",
  data: JSON.stringify(vm),
  contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
  success: action_Succeeded,
  error: action_Failed
});

function action_Succeeded(r) {
  console.log(r);
}

function log_Failed(r1, r2, r3) {
  alert("fail");
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to convert this to C#. My app is using .NET 2.0. From what I can tell, I need to do something like the following:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
  string json = "?";
  client.UploadString("http://www.mysite.com/1.0/service/action", json);
}
```

I'm a little stuck at this point. I'm not sure what `json` should look like. I'm not sure if I need to set the content type. If I do, I'm not sure how to do that. I also saw `UploadData`. So, I'm not sure if I'm even using the right method. In a sense, the serialization of my data is my problem.

Can someone tell me what I'm missing here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You need a json serializer to parse your content, probably you already have it,
for your initial question on how to make a request, this might be an idea:

```
var baseAddress = "http://www.example.com/1.0/service/action";

var http = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(baseAddress));
http.Accept = "application/json";
http.ContentType = "application/json";
http.Method = "POST";

string parsedContent = <<PUT HERE YOUR JSON PARSED CONTENT>>;
ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
Byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(parsedContent);

Stream newStream = http.GetRequestStream();
newStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
newStream.Close();

var response = http.GetResponse();

var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
var content = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

hope it helps,

Comment: what should "parsedContent" look like? Unfortunately, I need to manually create my JSON in this scenario. Thank you.

Comment: Can it just look like JSON? Or do I need to do some kind of special encoding is what I'm getting at.

Comment: @EelsFan usually is not a problem to choose any JSON parser, you can always JSON.Net to parse a .net object into JSON, but in my experience there were some cloud services that had a different JSON parser version and I had to make some tweaks. Do what is best for your scenario, this discussion might help you too see some issues without JSON.Net http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573119/how-to-parse-json-without-json-net-library

Comment: Why do you use ASCIIEncoding, and not UTF8? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9254967/109392.

Comment: +1 I first tried similar to OP using `WebClient`, and did not get it to work. Then I tried this sollution, and it worked like a charm.  
I was  using `UTF8Encoding` instead of `ASCIIEncoding` to create the byte array, because I see no reason to use ASCII, which reduces available characters in a way that is unacceptable. ASCII only has 127 characters in the charset.

Comment: I need t0 send some data to web api service ..where to define To Post data ?

Comment: and when i call this it returns protocolerror internall error 500 when u get web response..any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: thank you , your way is the best solution to send this data to my api:
{
  "applications": ["com.example.app"],
  "notification": {
    "title": "MyTitle",
    "content": "MyContent"
  }
}

Answer (score 218):

The question is already answered but I think I've found the solution that is simpler and more relevant to the question title, here it is:

```
var cli = new WebClient();
cli.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
string response = cli.UploadString("http://some/address", "{some:\"json data\"}");
```

*PS: In the most of .net implementations, but [not in all](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/silverlight/dotnet-windows-silverlight/tt0f69eh(v=vs.95)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) WebClient is IDisposable, so of cource it is better to do 'using' or 'Dispose' on it. However in this particular case [it is not really necessary](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/9714/using-statement-in-context-of-streams-and-webclients).*

Comment: And, to make your json "readable": (in vb.net)
    Dim json = <JSON>
    {
      "field1": "value1",
      "status": "pending",
      "objField": {
        "field2": true
      }
    }</JSON>.ToString

Comment: But what about inerpolating parameters into that json string?

Answer (score 81):

The following example demonstrates how to POST a JSON via [WebClient.UploadString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms144236(v=vs.80).aspx):

```
var vm = new { k = "1", a = "2", c = "3", v=  "4" };
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
   var dataString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vm);
   client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");
   client.UploadString(new Uri("http://www.contoso.com/1.0/service/action"), "POST", dataString);
}
```

> Prerequisites: [Json.NET library](https://json.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I think that should be UploadStringAsync if you are using the completed event.

Comment: You could omit the `POST` argument as `UploadString` implicitly uses this method as default. Furthermore you may want to add `client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "application/json");` if you expect `JSON` as return.

Comment: Does WebClient actually implement IDisposable?  I'm working in .NET Framework 4.7.1 a few years later and I don't see it.

Comment: @bubbleking I clicked F12 on WebClient and see that it is a Component and Component implements IDisposable
`public class WebClient : Component`
`public class Component : MarshalByRefObject, IComponent, IDisposable`