# How to POST data of this sort via HttpClient?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, http

Below is the request that I want to send. How do I do this via HttpClient? The endpoint is created in WebAPI.

[image: Request]

The endpoint code is something like this:

```
public string Post([FromBody]string sentence) {
    return sentence;
}
```

This is what I am trying:

```
public async static void getComponents(string inputString) {
        using (var client = new HttpClient()) {
            // New code:
            Console.WriteLine("sadsadsad");
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:2500/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

            var abc = client.PostAsync("/api/image", new StringContent(inputString, "application/json")).Result;
            Console.WriteLine(abc.ToString());
        }
    }
```

The request is received on the server side, but the parameter is null. I get 415 Unsupported Media Type when I try adding application/json just to the DefaultRequestHeaders.

Comment: I primarily want to know how to set the body data as this(without any parameter name or equal tos).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [POSTing JSON to URL via WebClient in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091300/posting-json-to-url-via-webclient-in-c-sharp). Answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/24085601/3745022

Comment: @EugenePodskal I am trying what the selected answer on that questions says, but to no avail.

Comment: "to no avail" is not a proper problem statement - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: Also, I have told you to use the second answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091300/posting-json-to-url-via-webclient-in-c-sharp. The first one uses vanilla WebRequest.

Comment: @EugenePodskal sorry, I updated my question to HttpClient, not WebClient.