# Getting '405 Method not allowed' when accessing a web API through my ASP.NET web form

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I used JSON to pass my variables as per the request of my API provider... I am attaching the code below:

```cs
string url = "http://api-v2.happay.in/auth/v1/adduser";
string token = "fcd853a15a6e97b8834255dde74cd99527";

string dataToUpload = "{"requestedId":"12389","userId":"134474","firstName":"Maredu Laxmi","lastName":"","emailId":"arar@gmail.com","mobileNo":"096518644","dob":"1978-02-26","gender":"Female","title":"Ms","password":"","metaFields":{"EmpId":"12389","Grade":"D6","Location":"Hyderabad"},"supervisors":[{"supervisorId":"1024","roleName":"RP"},{"supervisorId":"1025","roleName":"RP"}]}";

var cli = new WebClient();

cli.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
cli.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Bearer " + token;

string response = cli.UploadString(url, "POST", dataToUpload);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091300/posting-json-to-url-via-webclient-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

`405 Method Not Allowed` means that the endpoint you're trying to call (`http://api-v2.happay.in/auth/v1/adduser`) doesn't support the method you're trying to use (`POST`).

From [RFC 7231, Section 6.5.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.5):

> The 405 (Method Not Allowed) status code indicates that the method received in the request-line is known by the origin server but not supported by the target resource.

Are you sure the endpoint supports the `POST` method?

The RFC also states that

> The origin server MUST generate an `Allow` header field in a 405 response containing a list of the target resource's currently supported methods.

You could check the response and see if they've followed the specification and included an `Allow` header.

Comment: I'm not sure what to say... It's obviously something on their end. If they've said "`POST` this payload to `http://api-v2.happay.in/auth/v1/adduser`", your code looks fine. You should talk to them and make sure the information you have is correct.

Comment: i suspected  this section - cli.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Bearer " + token; Is it right?

Comment: Yes, it looks fine. Whether it's valid or not, I can't say :P