# C# WebClient upload JSON in POST request

Tags: c#, json, webclient

I have some data in JSON format that I need to send to a web address via a POST request. The data resembles the following example:

```
[
 {
  "Id":0,
  "Name":"John"
 },
 {
  "Id":0,
  "Name": "James"
 }
]
```

I would normally have no problem uploading the data as a `NameValueCollection` using the `WebClient.UploadValues()` method:

```
using (WebClient Client = InitWebClient()) // InitWebClient() initialises a new WebClient and sets the BaseAddress and Encoding properties
{
    NameValueCollection Values = new NameValueCollection
    {
        {"Id", "0"},
        {"Name", "John"}
    };
    Client.UploadValues("/api/example", "POST", Values);                
}
```

However as this JSON request is a list (and must always be in the form of a list even if there is only one item being uploaded) I am at a loss as to how this is done.

Due to programming constraints I need to do all of this using the WebClient object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [POSTing JSON to URL via WebClient in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091300/posting-json-to-url-via-webclient-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Someone answered this question already but their answer was removed for some reason. Their solution was valid, however, so I've thrown together a rough implementation of it below (it's not at all dynamic but it should help others who have a problem similar to mine):

```
using (WebClient Client = InitWebClient())
{

    List<MyJsonObject> Items = new List<MyJsonObject>();

    // The following could easily be made into a for loop, etc:
    MyJsonObject Item1 = new MyJsonObject() {
        Id = 0,
        Name = "John"
    };
    Items.Add(Item1);
    MyJsonObject Item2 = new MyJsonObject() {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "James"
    };
    Items.Add(Item2);

    string Json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Items)
    Client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
    Client.UploadValues("/api/example", "POST", Json);

}
```

Here is the object that will be serialized:

```
public class MyJsonObject {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Similar but **not identical to** the following solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24085601/4541161

Comment: This doesn't work since UploadValues does not accept a string as 3th parameters!
Did you mean to user UploadString instead?

Comment: Agree with Dave - third param won't accept string. Sloppy answer.