# JSON array to C# array without Newtonsoft assembly

Tags: c#, .net, json, deserialization

I have a below json string and i am trying to get the "Company" array into C# Array

but i could not.. i have gone through other question over web, 
I found few serialization and Newtonsoft JSON Convert. but i don't have newtonsoft assembly on server as i am using a shared.. is there any way i get the

How can i get values from Json Array in C# Array and Json key value in C# string and integer array type?

I am using .net 4.0

```
{"Company": ["BMW", "Mercedes"], "Year":["2011","2014"], "request_id":"4"}
```

Comment: Considered using the built in .NET JavascriptSerializer? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573119/how-to-parse-json-without-json-net-library).

Comment: how about Array?  and i am using 4.0 @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it with REGEX

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

var jsonString = "{\"Company\": [\"BMW\", \"Mercedes\"], \"Year\":[\"2011\",\"2014\"], \"request_id\":\"4\"}";
var regexPattern = @"""Company"":\s\[(""\w+"".\s?)+";
Regex.Match(jsonString, regexPattern)
//Result => ["Company": ["BMW", "Mercedes"]]

Regex.Match(jsonString, regexPattern).Groups[1]
//["BMW", "Mercedes"]]
```

Comment: terrible idea to parse json with regex

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ He want to parse it without JSON.NET, so the best option in this case is Regex

Comment: Btw @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ terrible ideia is to downvote the answer because you want to use something that the OP wont.

Comment: There are two downvotes. So someone other than me (whom you consider ...) too doesn't like your answer.

Comment: If you absolutely cannot use any existing JSON parser, the best course of action would be to write your own.  The grammar is quite simple, and it wouldn't be too difficult to make a bug free one.