# Split string in square brackets from Google translator

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, split

I am receiving a data from a Google Language Translator service and need help splitting the data.

```
void Start()
{
    translateText("Hello, This is a test!", "en", "fr");
}

void translateText(string text, string fromLanguage, string toLanguage)
{
    string url = "https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=" + fromLanguage + "&tl=" + toLanguage + "&dt=t&q=" + Uri.EscapeUriString(text);
    StartCoroutine(startTranslator(url));
}

IEnumerator startTranslator(string url)
{
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);
    yield return www.Send();

    Debug.Log("Raw string Received: " + www.downloadHandler.text);

    LanguageResult tempResult = decodeResult(www.downloadHandler.text);

    Debug.Log("Original Text: " + tempResult.originalText);
    Debug.Log("Translated Text: " + tempResult.translatedText);
    Debug.Log("LanguageIso: " + tempResult.languageIso);

    yield return null;
}

LanguageResult decodeResult(string result)
{
    char[] delims = { '[', '\"', ']', ',' };
    string[] arr = result.Split(delims, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    LanguageResult tempLang = null;
    if (arr.Length >= 4)
    {
        tempLang = new LanguageResult();
        tempLang.translatedText = arr[0];
        tempLang.originalText = arr[1];
        tempLang.unknowValue = arr[2];
        tempLang.languageIso = arr[3];
    }
    return tempLang;
}

public class LanguageResult
{
    public string translatedText;
    public string originalText;
    public string unknowValue;
    public string languageIso;
}
```

then calling it with `translateText("Hello, This is a test!", "en", "fr");` from the `Start()` function which converts the English sentence to French with [**ISO 639-1 Code**](https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php).

The received data looks like this:

```
[[["Bonjour, Ceci est un test!","Hello, This is a test!",,,0]],,"en"]
```

I want to split it like this:

- Bonjour, Ceci est un test!
- Hello, This is a test!
- 0
- en

and put them into a string array in order.

I currently use this:

```
char[] delims = { '[', '\"', ']', ',' };
        string[] arr = result.Split(delims, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

This works if there is no comma  in the received string. If there is a comma, the splitted values are messed up.  What's the best way of splitting this?

**EDIT**:

With [Blorgbeard's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39133958/3785314) solution, the final working code is as below. Hopefully, this will help somebody else. This **shouldn't** be used for commercial purposes but for personal or school project.

```
void Start()
{
    //translateText("Hello, This is \" / \\ a test !", "en", "fr");
    //translateText("Hello, This is , \\ \" a test !", "en", "fr");
    translateText("Hello, This is a test!", "en", "fr");
}

void translateText(string text, string fromLanguage, string toLanguage)
{
    string url = "https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=" + fromLanguage + "&tl=" + toLanguage + "&dt=t&q=" + Uri.EscapeUriString(text);
    StartCoroutine(startTranslator(url));
}

IEnumerator startTranslator(string url)
{
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);
    yield return www.Send();

    Debug.Log("Raw string Received: " + www.downloadHandler.text);

    LanguageResult tempResult = decodeResult(www.downloadHandler.text);
    displayResult(tempResult);
    yield return null;
}

void displayResult(LanguageResult translationResult)
{
    Debug.Log("Original Text: " + translationResult.originalText);
    Debug.Log("Translated Text: " + translationResult.translatedText);
    Debug.Log("LanguageIso: " + translationResult.languageIso);
}

LanguageResult decodeResult(string result)
{
    string[] arr = Decode(result);

    LanguageResult tempLang = null;
    if (arr.Length >= 4)
    {
        tempLang = new LanguageResult();
        tempLang.translatedText = arr[0];
        tempLang.originalText = arr[1];
        tempLang.unknowValue = arr[2];
        tempLang.languageIso = arr[3];
    }
    return tempLang;
}

public class LanguageResult
{
    public string translatedText;
    public string originalText;
    public string unknowValue;
    public string languageIso;
}

private string[] Decode(string input)
{
    List<string> finalResult = new List<string>();

    bool inToken = false;
    bool inString = false;
    bool escaped = false;
    var seps = ",[]\"".ToArray();
    var current = "";
    foreach (var chr in input)
    {
        if (!inString && chr == '"')
        {
            current = "";
            inString = true;
            continue;
        }
        if (inString && !escaped && chr == '"')
        {
            finalResult.Add(current);
            current = "";
            inString = false;
            continue;
        }
        if (inString && !escaped && chr == '\\')
        {
            escaped = true;
            continue;
        }
        if (inString && (chr != '"' || escaped))
        {
            escaped = false;
            current += chr;
            continue;
        }
        if (inToken && seps.Contains(chr))
        {
            finalResult.Add(current);
            current = "";
            inToken = false;
            continue;
        }
        if (!inString && chr == '"')
        {
            inString = true;
            current = "";
            continue;
        }
        if (!inToken && !seps.Contains(chr))
        {
            inToken = true;
            current = "";
        }
        current += chr;
    }
    return finalResult.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Can the strings also have (escaped) quotes in them?

Comment: `Regex.Split` might be the way to go here, then you could specifically disregard `,` followed by a space, etc.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I just checked, yes it can have \" in it. This is so tricky to me.

Comment: @l'L'l It would be good if you provide an example.

Comment: It's *almost* JSON, you may be able to find a JSON parser that deals with empty array elements.

Comment: Yes, it's almost like json except that it has no attribute. I am doing this in Unity and therefore trying my best to avoid external libraries unless there is no other way of doing this.

Comment: The following regex can parse this string and handle \" : `"(.+?[^\\])"|(\d+)`

Comment: Looks like JSON.Net will actually handle it: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vlswks

Comment: @Blorgbeard  JSON.Net from NuGet is not compatible with Unity. The ported version is not [free](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/11347) I will likely go with this paid version if there is no other way. Thanks the code sample.

Comment: You might also try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573119/how-to-parse-json-without-json-net-library

Comment: @Blorgbeard  I wish I could but `System.Json` supports .NET >=4.5. Unity is uses <=.NET 3.5. Unity has built in Json serializer called [JsonUtility](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.html) they must have attributes for it to work. @just.ru that didn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could code up a simple parser yourself. Here's one I threw together (could use some cleaning up, but demonstrates the idea):

```
private static IEnumerable<string> Parse(string input) {
    bool inToken = false;
    bool inString = false;
    bool escaped = false;
    var seps = ",[]\"".ToArray();
    var current = "";
    foreach (var chr in input) {
        if (!inString && chr == '"') {
            current = "";
            inString = true;
            continue;
        }
        if (inString && !escaped && chr == '"') {
            yield return current;
            current = "";
            inString = false;
            continue;
        }
        if (inString && !escaped && chr == '\\') {
            escaped = true;
            continue;
        }
        if (inString && (chr != '"' || escaped)) {
            escaped = false;
            current += chr;
            continue;
        }
        if (inToken && seps.Contains(chr)) {
            yield return current;
            current = "";
            inToken = false;
            continue;
        }
        if (!inString && chr == '"') {
            inString = true;
            current = "";
            continue;
        }
        if (!inToken && !seps.Contains(chr)) {
            inToken = true;
            current = "";
        }
        current += chr;
    }
}
```

Here's a [jsfiddle demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hBd1Ek).

Comment: Nice out of the box thinking here +1

Comment: Is it possible to  make this into a function that returns string array of 4 that contains those result? So instead of `private static IEnumerable<string> Parse(string input)`, it becomes `private string [] Parse(string input)`?

Comment: Sure, just wrap it and call `.ToArray()` - or you could add to a `List<string>` instead of `yield return`ing values, and then return the list `.ToArray()`ed at the end.

Comment: I did something like [this](http://pastebin.com/D7TUUkS9) but that didn't work. Can you spot the problem?

Comment: Yes, `finalResult.Add(current);` should be in the places where I had `yield return current`, not just at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I spent time to test your solution and it works %100. Character escape works too. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Using `Regex.Split` you could do something like this for example:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
        var input ="[[[\"Bonjour, Ceci est un test!\",\"Hello, This is a test!\",,,0]],,\"en\"]";
        var parse = Regex.Split(input, "\\[|\\]|[^a-zA-Z ],|\",\"|\"|\"");
        foreach(var item in parse) {
            bool result = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(item) && (Char.IsLetter(item[0]) || Char.IsDigit(item[0]));
            if (result) {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
   }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Bonjour, Ceci est un test!
Hello, This is a test!
0
en
```

If you want everything that was split you can simply remove the `bool` check for alphacharacters.

Comment: Wow this is so close. The only problem is that it is skipping the `0`. Please take a look at the question again. You will see which `0`.

Comment: Still the-same thing I got  in your original answer.

Comment: @Programmer: See edit ( online example : https://dotnetfiddle.net/00jsNa )

Comment: I don't why but I am getting the-same result without the `0`.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said I don't know why. It works online but not on my side. Probably because of diffferent compiler or .NET version

Comment: 3.5, Unity3D. Don't even know the compiler name but I am 100% sure it is different from the one online. Just tired the modification....Still the-same result.

Comment: The-same thing. The 0 is the only thing left. FYI I ran out of upvotes but will be  able to at 8PM when time resets

Comment: @Programmer: Hey no worries... sometimes the order in which the regex pattern is placed makes a difference also. One more way you might try is `var parse = Regex.Split(input, "[^0-9a-zA-Z\" ],[^0-9a-zA-Z]*|[\\]\\[\"]");` - https://dotnetfiddle.net/WrGSwh ... The comma is the main problem in this situation, since it needs to be kept in the string, but also used as a delimiter.

Comment: Funny thing is that when I re-started Unity and the code in your answer works. The bad side is that it fails when I use `\"` in the string. Try it your self. Blorgbeard's answer passed that test. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You're welcome! Regex sometimes takes a lot of tinkering with more complex scenarios like you have, but at any rate glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a crazy idea - split by `"` and then by the rest (but won't work if there is `"` between the `"`'s)

```
var s = @"[[[""Bonjour, Ceci est un test!"",""Hello, This is a test!"",,,0]],,""en""]";

var a = s.Split('"').Select((x, i) => (i & 1) > 0 ? new[] { x } : x.Split("[],".ToArray(),  
                     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).SelectMany(x => x).ToArray();

Debug.Print(string.Join("|", a)); // "Bonjour, Ceci est un test!|Hello, This is a test!|0|en"
```

Comment: Works but fails when there is an escaped quote in it. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try regex for splitting. I tested with the sample you provided. It results like this.

```
    var str="[[[\"Bonjour, Ceci est un test!\",\"Hello, This is a test!\",,,0]],,\"en\"]";
    var splitted=Regex.Split(str,@"\[|\]|\,");
    foreach(var split in splitted){
       Console.WriteLine(split );
    }

   "Bonjour Ceci est un test!"
   "Hello This is a test!"
    0
   "en"
```

Comment: This did not work and the length is 15 instead of 4. I got **"Bonjour** in array[3].