# A simple parser from JSON string to Dictionary

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, localization, internationalization

I want to avoid importing a huge library to gain full JSON support.

My use case is REALLY simple: I need a parser to handle one specific case of JSON, where both key and value are strings, ie. `{ "name": "David" }`. No nesting, no arrays, no object serialization.

The reason being, I use JSON only for i18n, and I have structure my translation files to be flat JSON.

- Is it a good idea to hand roll my own parser?
- Is there one out there already?
- Are there easier solutions to my problem?

EDIT: yes, I do know JSON.net is the defacto solution for .NET, but it's not the solution for Unity (not natively). I really only need a tiny portion of its power.

Comment: Note: but I do want the flexibility of not needing to writing a class for my JSON object, which is why I pick Dictionary as my desired output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I deserialize JSON to a simple Dictionary<string,string> in ASP.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net)

Comment: @bansi could you please point out which answer applies to my question? Especially knowing JSON.net does not support Unity natively.

Comment: @bansi this is a kind of duplicate but not exact because the answer suggested is JSON.Net which OP doesnt want.

Comment: If you want `only a tiny portion of its power` it is better you hand roll a parser. All generic solutions out there try to go for a complete solution.

Comment: I have one exception rule: if it's built-in, and does what I want, then I say why not :) JSON.NET isn't though.

Comment: OK I found one SO question that address this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573119/how-to-parse-json-without-json-net-library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I found one! https://github.com/zanders3/json

Has decent tests, minimal features and likely designed for my specific use case.

To load a JSON file:

```
Dictionary<string, object> locales = new Dictionary<string, object>();

TextAsset file = Resources.Load(name) as TextAsset;
var locale = file.text.FromJson<object>();
locales.Add(name, locale);
```

To use the JSON dictionary:

```
string activeLocale = "en-US";
var locale = locales[activeLocale] as Dictionary<string, object>;
var translation = locale[key] as string;
```

Dead simple.

Answer (score 2):

[`System.Json`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.json%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) might do the trick for you.

The `JsonValue.Parse()` Method parses JSON text and returns a `JsonValue` like

```
JsonValue value = JsonValue.Parse(@"{ ""name"": ""David"" }");
```

You can also have a look at The [`JavaScriptSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) class is used internally by the asynchronous communication layer to serialize and deserialize the data that is passed between the browser and the Web server.

```
var Names = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<YourNameClass>(json);
```

Comment: You are right, JsonValue is close enough for my case, do see this SO question for more complete usage of JsonValue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573119/how-to-parse-json-without-json-net-library

Comment: Oh wait, except Unity doesn't have System.Json namespace, as it's .Net 3.0-ish...

Comment: Yeah it is introduced in 4.5

Answer (score 0):

Super simple Json parsing for Json strings like: { "name1": "David", "name2": "David" }. If you don't need to handle quoted commas and colons, eg {"weapons":"gun,mashine gun,supergun:2"} - change Regex.Split to simple String.Split.

```
private Dictionary<string, string> ParseJson(string content)
    {
        content = content.Trim(new[] { '{', '}' }).Replace('\'', '\"');
    
        var trimmedChars = new[] { ' ','\"' };
    
        //regex to split only unquoted separators
        Regex regxComma = new Regex(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))");
        Regex regxColon = new Regex(":(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))");
        
        return regxComma.Split(content)
                        .Select(v => regxColon.Split(v))
                        .ToDictionary(v => v.First().Trim(trimmedChars), v => v.Last().Trim(trimmedChars));
    }
```