# How read value from json with out using json.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I got a response from a webservice as shown below

```
{
"header":    {
  "sourceId": "1002",
  "mndAction": "CREATE",
  "msgId": "msg10022",
  "errMsg": null,
  "txnStatusFlg": "1",
  "successMsg": "SUCCESS"
},
"response": {"responseString": "Required Data"}
}
```

I want to get the value of responseString from the above json data.

For the response

```
{"Status":"success","DocRepoId":225,"Details":"success",
"ErrorCode":"","responseString": "Required Data"}
```

I used the code

```
 var deserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
 var someObject = deserializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>
 (response);     
 string responseString= someObject["responseString"].ToString();
```

to get the value of responseString but in this case its showing error.
I'm looking for a solution without using json.net or anything similar.
My project is on .net version 3.5.

Comment: So i would use `Newtonsoft.Json` - install it with Nuget-Installer and deserialize it this way `RootObject r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);`

Comment: One way is create an object with that structure and use deserializer.Deserialize<ThatObject>(json).

Comment: @LenglBoy OP specifically said WITHOUT USING JSON OR SIMILAR

Comment: @LenglBoy thanks for the quick response but i can't use newtonsoft.json or json.net

Comment: @o_O oh thought only json.NET. Why not using the normal microsoft way which is included in .NET anyway? Little bit more complicated than the other Libs but working. Or build a own serializer fot this short json.

Comment: Some web services allow you to request either xml or json. If you can request xml then you can use XDocument to easily get your data.

Comment: @Mr.Ambivert is there a specific reason that you don't want to use Json.Net or similar. Maybe admin rights or something. If that is so, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573119/how-to-parse-json-without-json-net-library)

Comment: @bruno.almeida It will be so much helpfull if you provide me some more details

Comment: @o_O I will give it a try

Comment: @Crowcoder the only option is json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it goes an example of what i told you in comment.

Using this classes:

```
    class Test
    {
        public Response Response { get; set; }
    }

    class Response
    {
        public string ResponseString { get; set; }
    }
```

You can get what you want with this code:

```
        JavaScriptSerializer s = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        string json = @"{
            ""header"":    {
                                ""sourceId"": ""1002"",
              ""mndAction"": ""CREATE"",
              ""msgId"": ""msg10022"",
              ""errMsg"": null,
              ""txnStatusFlg"": ""1"",
              ""successMsg"": ""SUCCESS""
                            },
            ""response"": { ""responseString"": ""Required Data""}
                        }";


        Test t = s.Deserialize<Test>(json);

        var responseString = t.Response.ResponseString;
```

Comment: You saved my day

Comment: Nice. Forgot the s declaration, but you got it :)