# Accessing a JSON file

Tags: project.json

Please guys what code should I write on my .java file in android studio so I can be able to ACCESS and DISPLAY strings from the .JSON format below.

```
{

"question" : [

{
"id" : "0", 

" question " : " ", 

" options " :
   {
  "A" : " ", 
  "B" : " ", 
  "C" : " ", 
  "D" : " ", 
    }  , 

" answer" : " "
}  ,
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON without JSON.NET library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573119/how-to-parse-json-without-json-net-library)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)