# ASP.net WebMethod is returning complete page content rather than JSON data

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, ajax, json

I m trying a auto complete functionality for a textbox , where I am sending a get request to a webmethod which is returning complete page content rather than actual data as shown below.

[image]

i am using following C# code, while my all other methods with Post request are working fine

```
[WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true,ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public static string GetListOfUsers()
        {
            return "{'0701414001','0701414002'}";
        }
```

Comment: And it'd help if you showed the ajax call. Are you using $.ajax?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your parameters: you're calling `Email.aspx/GetListOfUusers?query=lkkjlk` but your `public static string GetListOfUsers()` does not contain a parameter name.

Try changing to this:

```
public static string GetListOfUsers(string query)
{
...
}
```

I'd also try removing this: `ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json` and see if it changes anything.

Comment: no adding parameters also doesn't results in desired results , also tried by removing ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json

Comment: Take  look at an answer I provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405458/return-json-data-from-asmx-web-service/ I used page methods too but then I switched to web services and it's much much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be achieved in the following most simple way as mentioned over here
in this article by creating ashx handler 
http://codeasp.net/articles/asp-net/212/using-jquery-autocomplete-in-asp-net

Article Demo
http://codeasp.net/assets/demos/articles/using-jquery-autocomplete-in-asp-net/using-jquery-autocomplete-in-asp-net-multiple.aspx