# Ajax call doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, jquery, json.net

I try to use ajax call in my aspx page. Here is my script:

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/ui/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebForm1.aspx/List",
            data: '{}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function () {
                alert('asd');
            }
        });

    });

</script>
</head>
```

Here is my server side code:

```
 [WebMethod]
 public static string[] List()
 {
      ...
 }
```

I put a break point List's first row but nothing happen. Do you have any suggestion, where I make a mistake?

Comment: Why are you using `POST` instead of `GET`? What do the developer tools tell you? Have you looked at the request headers? Response headers?

Comment: @Oded — Presumably because the POST verb is more appropriate for the task in question. There is nothing in the question that indicates what the task is, so no reason to assume that POST is inappropriate.

Comment: @Quentin - Fair enough. It's just that when I see no data being passed though, I don't feel that post semantics are appropriate.

Comment: I think the problem is with the way the parameters are defined.

Comment: @Oded — It's a cut down minimal test case.

Comment: @frenchie, I don't have any parameters.

Comment: I put an alert instead of ajax call codes, and it doesnt work too. I think the problem is in the $(document).ready(function () ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter you're specifying is json; but where's the json data?? `data: '{}',` is an object. Also, I'd check the url parameter. Presumably, you'd need to write your call like this:

```
var AjaxData = '{"ParameterName":""}';

 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../WebForm1.aspx/GetList",
            data: AjaxData ,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",....
```

And then on the server side, you should therefore specify that you're receiving a string, since that's the format of json data. I would also recommend changing the name of the WebMethod because `List` can be confusing. And finally, you're returning json, therefore you're returning a string and not an array. Server method like this:

```
 [WebMethod]
 public string GetList(string ParameterName)
 {
      ...
 }
```

Comment: I just made an edit, I think your URL might also be a problem. Also, I just saw that you're not sending parameters; made that edit as well.

Comment: aspx and aspx.cs files are in the same root. I add a comment to my question. I think, problem is in the document.ready function

Comment: Take a look at this answer, might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405458/return-json-data-from-asmx-web-service

Comment: Also, not sure if it's a typo in just the question, but the jquery file reference is missing. If it's also missing from the aspx then thaat would be an issue.