# web service in ASP .Net MVC application

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, web-services

I want to add a web service to asp .net mvc application as a model
any one has an idea how to do this ?

i wrote my web service:

```
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }

   [HttpPost]
   [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public string GetData(IDictionary<string, string> inputParam)
    {
        MusicStoreEntities db = new MusicStoreEntities();
        List<Category> categoriesList = new List<Category>();
        List<Song> songsList = new List<Song>();
        String sJSON = " ";


        int ID = 0 ;
        if (inputParam.ContainsKey("categoryId") ){
            ID = Int32.Parse(inputParam["categoryId"]);
        }

        if (ID == 0)
        {

            categoriesList = db.Albums.ToList();
            var oSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            sJSON = oSerializer.Serialize(categoriesList);

        }
        else {
            songsList = db.SongList.Where(d => d.categoryId == ID).ToList();
            var oSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            sJSON = oSerializer.Serialize(songsList);
        }

        return sJSON;

    } 
}
```

this web service must me invoked by android application

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use asmx services here, please have a look at below link having same concern: [Return Json Data from ASMX web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405458/return-json-data-from-asmx-web-service)

It would better if you can use [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) as you want to send some JSON data to Andriod application. It would REST based and light weighted and will require less configurations needed.

Hope it would be helpful.