# Connect javascript with asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, json

I'm with troubles to connect javascript with asp.net webforms method via ajax and json.

I have the javascript in one folder and page.aspx in the other for example:
- Account/createUser.aspx
- Script/actions/createuser.js

I already tried many things, for example, use before the method [Webmethod], in the ajax action change many things, but nothing works. In mostly of tentatives the google chrome give the error:

> POST .../Account/createUser.aspx/CheckUserName 401 (Unauthorized)

If I remove in javascript lines like: "dataType: json" and "contentType: application/json; charset=utf-8" the error disappears and enter on "complete" line...

I need instructions to resolve this problem... I search a lot of posts, follow many tutorials and nothing means work. 
For example: change my webconfig to accept any users, my routeconfig.cs...

Is something faling? What? Do I need to declare something to use json?

Javascript:

```
$("#USUserName").change(function () {
    alert($("#USUserName").val());
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "createUser.aspx/CheckUserName",
        data: '{username: "' + $("#USUserName").val() + '" }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        complete: function (jsondata, stat) {
            if (stat == "success") {
                var response = JSON.parse(jsondata.responseText).d;
                alert((response));
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert();
        }
    });
```

aspx.cs code:

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string CheckUserName(string username)
    {
        var existUser = context.user.Where(us => ((us.username).Equals(username))).Count();
        string returnValue = string.Empty;
        if (existUser.Equals(0))
        {
            returnValue = "test- yes!";

        }
        else
            returnValue = "test- no!";
        return returnValue;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe this is running in different domains? If yes then you have stomped with cross domain security, jsonp could help you.

Comment: Different folders are not different domains.

Comment: First suggestion: Depending on your browser, Install Firefox+Firebug, or Fiddler, or Chrome + Web Developer Tools + JSONview. These will give you visibility into your AJAX requests. Otherwise, you are flying blind as a developer.

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244696/how-to-return-json-with-asp-net-jquery

Comment: also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405458/return-json-data-from-asmx-web-service

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the WebMethod attribute to be able to call with ajax (if domain is the same).

C#

```
public partial class PageName: Page 
{
  [WebMethod]
  public static string MethodName()
  {
    return "success";
  }
}
```

JS

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "PageName.aspx/MethodName",
  data: "{}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg) {
    // Do something interesting here.
  }
});-
```

source : http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

If domain is different, you have to edit the cross domain policy :
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: The domain is the same. but give the same error:
POST http://localhos(...)/Account/createUser.aspx/GetDate 401 (Unauthorized)

Comment: I just tried again, it works fine. Can you make sure that your method is PUBLIC and STATIC?

Answer (score 0):

See MS docs:

> The ScriptMethodAttribute attribute is optional. (However, methods
>   that can be called from client script must have the
>   System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute attribute applied.). If a
>   method is not marked with ScriptMethodAttribute, the method will be
>   called by using the HTTP POST command and the response will be
>   serialized as JSON. You cannot override this setting from script.

If you just want JSON and are using an HTTP POST method, remove the optional [ScriptMethod ...] and make sure you just have [WebMethod]

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptmethodattribute.aspx

Comment: I already tried with [WebMethod] and the result was the same.