# jquery ajax call to asp.net webservice

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I am trying to call webservice method from Jquery ajax.

Here is my jquery code,

```
function abc() {

        alert("");
        $.ajax({
            type: "Get",
            url: "abc.asmx/HelloWorld",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            error: function (errorThrown) {
                console.log(errorThrown.d); 
                alert(errorThrown + "what's wrong?");
            },
            success: function (msg) {
                console.log(msg.d);
                alert(msg.d);
                return false;
                // Do something interesting here.
            }
        });
        return false; }
```

and my web method is following,

```
 [WebMethod]
public string HelloWorld() {
    return "Hello World";
}
```

the jquery error event is keep occuring. Not sure why it's happening

any help will be appreciated

thanks

Comment: What is the error? errorThrown?

Comment: Did you check the firebug/chrome console for error?

Comment: You don't need `data: "{}",` and what error are you seeing?

Comment: I checked it's giving "XMLHTTPOBJECR" and when i use errorThrown.d it's giving "undefined"

Comment: `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` makes no sense. You are making a GET request. There is no request body to describe the content type of.

Comment: `dataType: "json"` - you are overriding the content-type of the response and parsing it as JSON. `public string HelloWorld() {
    return "Hello World";
}` does not appear to return JSON.

Comment: Updated my answer. Just remove `.d`

Comment: Take a look at these 2 answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405458/return-json-data-from-asmx-web-service and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244696/how-to-return-json-with-asp-net-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing the `[ScriptService]` attribute on my `WebService` class, similar to this:

```
[ScriptService]
public class MyWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService 
{
    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld() {
        return "Hello World";
    }    
}
```

Now it's working perfectly.

Comment: I added some sample code how this might look like so future users with less knowledge in the area may find this useful. If this is not how you used it, please add your sample code showing the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as you are expecting a JSON result from server and adding `ScriptMethod` will enable javascript to call your method

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string HelloWorld()
{
 return "Hello World";
}
```

Also check [How to let an ASMX file output JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211348/how-to-let-an-asmx-file-output-json)

Comment: @xyz, Updated my answer. Just remove `.d`

Comment: @xyz, If you are running in firefox, check the console and see the detailed information about the error.

Answer (score -2):

I guess that you need to specify what kind of request the method will response.

something like this

```
[HttpGet]
public string HelloWorld() {
    return "Hello World";
}

Or use the convention

public string Get() {
    return "Hello World";
}
```