# JSON - ButtonClick in asp.net is not firing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

Hi iam using JSON for the first time in asp.net.

My aspx code :

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#imgbtnGo').click(function () {
          alert("Hi");
    var valService = $("#ddlService").val();
          alert("valService"+ valService);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/VoyageOneService.svc/BindVoyageDetails?valService =" + valService,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
        dataType: "Json",
        processdata: true,
        success: function (msg) {
            ServiceSucceeded(msg);
        },
        error: ServiceFailed
    });

   });
   function ServiceSucceeded(result) {
                alert(result);
  }
</script>
```

And

```
         <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlService" runat="server" Width="100px" TabIndex="1"></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnGo" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/image_repository/go_icon.png"  />

     <asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptProxyVoy" runat="server">
       <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/VoyageOneService.svc" />
    </Services>
</asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
```

..

My Service is :

```
             public string BindVoyageDetails(int serviceid)
{
                     /// Coding here..
                   Serialization
           MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(VoyageMaster));
    serializer.WriteObject(stream, objVoyMstr);
    stream.Position = 0;
    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
    return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

}

I hope iam perfect in Service but iam not getting that service fired when i click on my button....

I can not find out the reason can any one please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using button Id like this

```
$('#imgbtnGo').click(function ()
```

butt `imgbtnGo` is not the actual ID of button after rendering of the page so either you can get it's `ClinetID` or 
you need to set `ClientIDMode="Static"` for the button.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnGo" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/image_repository/go_icon.png" ClientIDMode="Static"  />
```

Comment: I have changed it to static mode but still i could not get result. when i check result in alert its NULL, when when i check in service json is returning values

Answer (score 0):

Apart from suggested changes in JavaScript as given by Sachin
You need to add following attribute to web method (In order to make it emit response in JSON):

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
```

Source: [ASP.NET JSON Web Service Response format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238672/asp-net-json-web-service-response-format)

Answer (score 0):

Also you need use the binding `binding="webHttpBinding"` , go through the below link 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/132809/Calling-WCF-Services-using-jQuery