# ascx WebMethod to return already encoded JSON string

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, json, web-services

This is a fairly simple question but googleing for the answer is somewhat challenging.

I have a webmethod which, for reasons that are not relevant, has a string which has already been JSON encoded. I want to return this JSON packet to the client.

C#

```
[WebMethod(true)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string GetJSONString()
{
  return MethodWhichReturnsJSONString();
}
private string MethodWhichReturnsJSONString()
{
  return "{\"Message\":\"Hard coded string for demo purposes\"}";
}
```

JS

```
Namepsace.Service.GetJSONString(function(data)
{
  console.log(data);
  var obj=JSON.parse(data);
});
```

Data contains a JSON encoded string and obj contains the actual obj;

During transit the data will have been double encoded adding to processing time and bandwidth requirements.

Is there a way to skip this redundant overhead without de serialising the packet at the server and returning an object, perhaps with an additional attribute on the web method?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is the "[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json)]" line.  That is telling the framework to serialize the return object to JSON, which in essence is double-encoding since your object is already a JSON encoded string.  The simple thing would be to remove that line for your demo.  To really do things right though, leave it in there and make the property class an actual complex object and let the framework serialize it to JSON for you.

Similar Q/A to help aid understanding: [ASP.NET JSON Web Service Response format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238672/asp-net-json-web-service-response-format)

Comment: Actually, in the original question (as stated) converting a complex object could only be achieved by deserialising the existing JSON packet (which comes from SQL) but I've had to re-engineer this code now anyway for other reasons so  I do infact have an object graph after all.